# asp.net c# gridview - how to know which cell clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which has 2 header rows as below

```
| Name  |   Subject1    |  Subject2    |
|       |Theory | Viva  |Theory | Viva |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|------|
| John  |       |       |       |      |
| Ann   |       |       |       |      |
```

When user clicks on a cell I want to know whether he has clicked on theory or viva column.

By using gvStudent.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString(); I am able to retrieve the student ID which I have set as datakey for the gridview. Hence able to identify which row he clicked.

By using gvStudent.HeaderRow.Cells[index].Text; I am able to identify which Subject he clicked.

But how to know whether he has clicked on Theory or Viva column. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Dynamic Code

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
{ 
     int studentid=gvStudent.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

     foreach (GridViewRow row in gvStudent.Rows) 
     { 
        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells) 
        { 
           if (cell is DataControlFieldCell) 
           { 
               string subjectselected= gvStudent.HeaderRow.Cells[ind].Text; 
            } 
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: How are you handling the click event?

Comment: how you split the column as Theory and Viva, follow the same to find

Comment: protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        int studentid=gvStudent.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvStudent.Rows)
        {

                        foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                       {
                                if (cell is DataControlFieldCell)
                                 {
   string subjectselected= gvStudent.HeaderRow.Cells[ind].Text;
}

Comment: Please edit relevant code into the post, don't use comments for that

Comment: Just use the CellClick event. The DataGridViewCellEventArgs will contain what you need. (e.ColumnIndex)

Comment: i am dynamically creating a data table in page load and adding both header rows also dynamically.

Comment: e.ColumnIndex will only return the header Row 1 
I actually want header row 2. 
Can you please tell how to get that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean sorry. You have both ColumnIndex and RowIndex in the click event.

Comment: can you please paste the dynamic code with your question

Comment: Header row 1 is - Name / subject1 / subject 2. 
Header row 2 is  Theory / Viva  / theory / viva. 
Using column index and row index if i try 
gvStudent.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[columnindex].Text then i get the marks for each subject. 
What i want is when user clicks a cell i want to know if the header for that clicked cell is subject1 - theory or subject1- viva or subject2- theory or subject2 - viva. 
Using gvStudent.HeaderRow.Cells[columnindex].Text I can get only first header row eg: Name/ subject 1 / subject 2
But how to know if theory or viva which column cell user has clicked?

Comment: is there something like gvStudent.HeaderRow[2].Cells[columnindex].text to see if it returns theory or viva (Header row 2)